# Is there a way to display plots as they build in Shiny instead of waiting for all of them?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a Shiny Dashboard with many plots, all of which take multiple seconds to build. Once the last one builds, they all display. I would like instead for each plot to display as soon as it completes. I understand R is single-threaded, but it seems as though there must be a way to "return execution to the display code" or something like that.

This code demonstrates the issue:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Page loading test"
  , h1("Page loading test")
  , plotOutput("plot1")
  , plotOutput("plot2")
  , plotOutput("plot3")
  , plotOutput("plot4")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
     Sys.sleep(10)
     plot(rnorm(50))
   })

   output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
     Sys.sleep(10)
     plot(rnorm(50))
   })

   output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
     Sys.sleep(10)
     plot(rnorm(50))
   })

   output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
     Sys.sleep(10)
     plot(rnorm(50))
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

*The sleeps are merely to emulate slow execution.*

It takes 40s for the page to display. I would like the page to take 10s to display plot1, then an additional 10s to display plot2, etc. Is there a call like UpdatePage() that can be called at the bottom of each plot function?

On my page, I have loading animations running so the user is aware activity is occurring, which makes it even more obvious when they load at once.

I could, of course, have a simpler page, but then it wouldn't be a dashboard. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reactiveTimer()` to refresh your page regularly.

And you can save your plots in a `list` of plots to print them immediately at each refresh.

I had to reorder the `renderPlot` functions so the `step` iterator only renders one plot at a time

Also I chose not to start the first render right away to plot "Loading" plots.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  title = "Page loading test"
  , h1("Page loading test")
  , plotOutput("plot1")
  , plotOutput("plot2")
  , plotOutput("plot3")
  , plotOutput("plot4")
)

# Loading plot
plot(-1:1, -1:1, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
text(0,0, "Loading",cex = 5)
loading <- recordPlot()

plotlist <- vector("list",4) 
step <- 0 # which plot should be rendered next

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(10, session)
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({autoInvalidate();
    if(step>4){plotlist[[4]]}
    else if(step==4){step <<- step+1
    print("rendering step 4")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    plotlist[[4]] <<- {plot(rnorm(50));recordPlot()}} else loading
  })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({autoInvalidate();
    if(step>3){plotlist[[3]]}
    else if(step==3){step <<- step+1
    print("rendering step 3")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    plotlist[[3]] <<- {plot(rnorm(50));recordPlot()}} else loading
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({autoInvalidate();
    if(step>2){plotlist[[2]]}
    else if(step==2){step <<- step+1
    print("rendering step 2")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    plotlist[[2]] <<- {plot(rnorm(50));recordPlot()}} else loading
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({autoInvalidate();
    if(step>1){plotlist[[1]]}
    else if(step==1){step <<- step+1
    print("rendering step 1")
    Sys.sleep(10)
    plotlist[[1]] <<- {plot(rnorm(50));recordPlot()}} else {step <<-1;loading}
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```