# shiny server takes forever to initialize

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a server.R running two linear maximization functions, and two quadratic programming optimization functions. One of them optimizes a 9x9 matrix, the other a 19x19 matrix.

There are about ~200 inputs from Shiny.

I added this loading function from one of the other threads:

```
conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
  tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")
)
```

The issue is that the program will sit blank for about 10 seconds, then the loading message will pop up for half a second, then all the outputs will show up. That makes me think that it isn't computing anything in the 10 seconds it hangs. What could be causing that 10 second dead time between launching the Shiny webpage and then actually getting an output?

I know it isn't a calculation thing because if I change the optimization parameters, it only displays the loading panel for a split second.

Comment: You can have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531345)

Comment: That isn't relevant to my issue. I did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `options(shiny.error = browser)` from the code seemed to fix the issue.

That and restarting the server fixed it.